# Failed to achieve intended project outcome, what to put on design fair poster?

Tags: engineering, poster, projects

I have been working on an ultrasonic transducer technology for a while now. This project involves a very novel components that has not yet been established to work. Because of the novelty of this project, there were a lot of difficulty, and with the schools' design fair looming, our team have encountered a very delicate issue with power consumption which will require some time to find a solution.

So what the team has done is to apply a common, industry standard approach you can find anyone on the Internet. In essence, the novelty of this project is gone and has became something anyone could do.

We are a little unsure as to what we should demonstrate for the design fair. On the one hand we can show the technology working, but our poster has to reflect that it is nothing novel (in fact has been done in the year prior) and all components are off of the shelve. On the other hand we can show an incomplete project with the intended novel technique on the poster, but without anything to show for.

What should we do in this case?

Comment: progress/results so far, plus the issues still left to resolve, and maybe some hints at solutions that you're considering testing given the time & funding?

Comment: Details of exactly why what you have tried doesn't work, and suggestions as to what might?

Comment: " Future Work "

Comment: This sounds similar to the question [What do I do if my results are not ready before a conference?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32848/what-do-i-do-if-my-results-are-not-ready-before-a-conference/32866).